# Делал чат-бота для ВК на Питоне и появилась ошибка KeyError: 'user_id', что делать в этом случае?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import vk_api, random

token = 'TOKEN но скрыт'

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
vk._auth_token()

while True:
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset":0, "count":20, "filter":"unanswered"})
    text = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['text']
    user_id = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['user_id']
    vk_method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id ,"message":"Ты пытаешься мне что-то сказать, но я тебя не понимаю, я бот, воспользуйся командой <<помощь>>, и узнай на какие команды я могу тебе ответить","random_id":random.randint(1, 10000)})
```

Ошибка имеет вид:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Бот.py", line 11, in <module>
    user_id = messages['items'][0]['last_message']["user_id"]
KeyError: 'user_id'
```

Comment: Может это сообщение не от юзера? )  Проверять `if 'user_id' in messages['items'][0]['last_message']` и только тогда брать значение и вообще логику дальше использовать.

Comment: Проверяйте, какие данные вернул ВК и есть ли там user_id вообще `print(messages['items'][0]['last_message'])`

Comment: andreymal, есть from_id (мой вк) и id (думаю это ид сообщения, но не так много пока что разбираюсь в самом питоне и не совсем понимаю всё что выдает консоль)